# What's difference between Promise.reject(error) and return error in Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a general query about Axios and Promises. Maybe someone can help me clear this concept.

Basic Interceptor of Axios includes:

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

My question is what's the difference between returning error as

```
Project.reject(error);
```

and as

```
return error;
```

This response and error goes to the Request 'then' amd 'catch' blocks respectively I believe. But what's the difference if we use Promise.resolve and Promise.reject?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried (it's that easy!) and the difference is that by returning a rejected promise (`return Promise.reject(error)`), you tell `axios` that the response has an error condition and that the upstream code should be notified about it (`axios(…).catch(…)` will trigger).

When returning just the error (`return error`), you're telling `axios` to basically ignore the error and the upstream code will not know about it (`axios(…).then(…)` will trigger).